# What should I do with this Q...? Edit or repost with new details?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

[What is the Linux equivalent of the Windows registry?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/what-is-the-linux-equivalent-of-the-windows-registry)

Already 16 votes on one answer so far. It seems like an answered Q from my perspective. I'm planning to post the information about windows registry locations. But I would be interested to know where people think I should do so for Best Question Quality.

Comment: For the record, the registry info goes like this: First, expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, find SYSTEM, and then expand CurrentControlSet, expand Control, expand Class...
then find {4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318} and click UpperFilters. Delete UpperFilters & LowerFilters.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, I think you should post a new question at [Super User](https://superuser.com/). You've asked a very general question, and got a very general answer.
Your actual underlying question is very different, a specific question about a specific piece of hardware. I recommend SU because understanding what that registry setting means requires some knowledge of Windows. You should also give the model of your drive, in case someone knows a Linux solution without knowing the Windows one.

As a more general matter, in my experience, this kind of solved-looking question is unlikely to get much further attention, so don't hesitate to post a new question if you realise your first question was interpreted in a different direction from what you intended. If your new question looks very similar to your old one (which is not the case here), you might add a note to your new question linking to the old one and summarizing in one line or so how the new question asks something different.

Answer (score 1):

It feels like 2 questions... take the answer about the registry and ask another about your drive, since you've now learned there is no registry, also bonus points if you remove the questions about the drive from the original question entirely. In that question be sure to post exactly what the problem is with the dvd-rw and details about the drive. I don't think there's any reason to ask on SU personally.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think Gilles answer actually covers your whole question; it covers how there's no "Linux registry", and what you'll probably have to do to try and fix the problem on Linux. Adding the Windows registry instructions likely won't help, since (as Gilles says) they don't really translate to Linux at all.

If you do want to add them, you probably want them in a separate question. I would edit the old question to just ask about the registry (pull the DVD part out), and post a new question that asks about the DVD problem and doesn't mention a "Linux registry" at all. This will make the second part of Gilles' answer a bit inapplicable though, so you probably just want to leave it alone

---

### Old question

#### What is the Linux equivalent of the Windows registry?

Many configuration settings on Windows are stored in a centralized location, the Windows registry. Is there an equivalent centralized store on Linux?

### New question

#### What is the Linux equivalent of drive upper/lower filters in Windows?

I have a DVD+-RW drive that has quit working. Apparently many users of this laptop model experience the same problem under Windows and are required to edit the registry to correct the problem, like so:

- Expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
- Find SYSTEM
- Expand CurrentControlSet
- Expand Control
- Expand Class
- Find {4D36E965-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
- Delete UpperFilters & LowerFilters.

I'm hoping to adapt that fix to a Linux machine. Where should I look to make a similar edit?